# live Java GUI Builder like FireBug extension for HTML and CSS

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have been a Web Developer for more than 5 years and is now diving into Java as well. I have used NetBeans and its Drag & Drop feature. But due to habbit I like to code everything manually not by NetBean's Drag and Drop.

Everything is perfect but when it comes to put different components on different locations on a JPanel, it becomes really pain to know what co-ordinates for x and y to put components at.

When it's website developing in HTML and CSS, we have many tools like FireFox's FireBug extension etc which help us in adjusting CSS live.

Is there anything for Java as well so we can adjust our component live and then when we know x and y, we can make actual code in Java.

For example, I create a button and put in a jframe, when I run it, I can adjust it's location and then change my actual code.

I don't know it's either possible or not. But as there are Gurus so asking if they would be knowing of some tool.

Comment: No, there is not any tool to do that. But java is a high level programming language, you can get location of any component at any time with good coding or debugging. Please visit [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/), it will help you a lot in understanding how it work. And in your case you are working with [group layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) tool found in netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to manually set x / y / size of components.  Use [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and call `pack()` on your JFrame to size and place your components.  Due to differences in screen size and resolution it is very difficult to have your GUI look nice on all systems using manual sizing and placement. Have a try with layout managers and come back with a specific question if you can't get the specific visual look you want.